# How to get the index of an element inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Having the following array:

```
  const options = [
    {
      id: 'Coffee',
      type: 'radio-group',
    },
    {
      id: 'Tea',
      type: 'radio-group',
    },
    {
      id: 'Milk',
      type: 'radio-group',
      disabled: true,
    },
  ];
```

and the object:

```
const toCheck =  { id: 'Coffee', type: 'radio-group'};
```

Because `options[0]` is equal to `toCheck`, shouldn't `options.indexOf(toCheck)` return `0`?

It returns `-1`, is it a way to return the desired value?

Comment: Different objects with the same values aren't `===` to each other. You will need to use `.findIndex` to find the index of an object with the same properties.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an object property, here I used the id for these examples:

```js
const options = [{
    id: 'Coffee',
    type: 'radio-group',
  },
  {
    id: 'Tea',
    type: 'radio-group',
  },
  {
    id: 'Milk',
    type: 'radio-group',
    disabled: true,
  },
];
let c = options.findIndex((x) => x.id === 'Coffee');
console.log(c);
let m = options.findIndex((x) => x.id === 'Milk');
console.log(m);
```